# how to delete press and hold arrow keys. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, game-engine, keypress, game-development

I developing game and use arrow button for move character but I don’t want to user press and hold keyboard(arrow button) when play my game. how to detect it?
Needs details or clarity

My Code: KeyDown is image JumpFrog

```
private void Game_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                goLeft = false;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.frogL;
                
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                goRight = false;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.frogR;
                
                break;
            case Keys.Up:
                goUp = false;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.frog1;
                
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                goDown = false;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.frog1D;
                break;
        }
        
        
    }
```

KeyUp is image frog don't jump.

```
private void Game_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                goLeft = false;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.frogL;
                
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                goRight = false;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.frogR;
                
                break;
            case Keys.Up:
                goUp = false;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.frog1;
                
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                goDown = false;
                player.Image = Properties.Resources.frog1D;
                break;
        }
       
    }
    private int speed = 25;
    private void MoveFrog()
    { 
        if(goLeft == true && player.Left > 25)
        {
            player.Left -= speed;
           

        }
        if(goRight == true && player.Left < 370)
        {
            player.Left += speed;
            

        }
        if(goUp == true && player.Top > 10)
        {
            player.Top -= speed;
           
        }
        if (goDown == true && player.Top < 395)
        {
            player.Top += speed;
           
        }
    }
```

I pressed the up arrow key without releasing it, causing my frog to keep moving forward. And the sound of the jump was not over.how can i solve it I want to hold down and the frog doesn't go on and on.
Needs details or clarity